# Want to integrate argo server with keycloak

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, argo-workflows

I tried in incognito as wellbut same issue exists.

Currently I have added in server-deployment.yaml
args: - server - --auth-mode - sso

And in values.yaml

```
sso:
# #SSO configuration when SSO is specified as a server auth mode.
# #All the values are requied. SSO is activated by adding --auth-mode=sso
# #to the server command line.
#
# #The root URL of the OIDC identity provider.
issuer: http://<keycloak_ip>/auth/realms/demo
# #Name of a secret and a key in it to retrieve the app OIDC client ID from.
clientId:
name: argo
key: client-id
# #Name of a secret and a key in it to retrieve the app OIDC client secret from.
clientSecret:
name: "argo-server-sso"
key: client-secret
# # The OIDC redirect URL. Should be in the form /oauth2/callback.
redirectUrl: http:///argo/oauth2/callback
```

And in keycloak ui , I have created client and client credentials.

```
kubectl create secret generic "argo-server-sso" --from-literal=client-secret=9a9c60ba-647d-480c-b6fa-82c19caad26a
kubectl create secret generic "argo" --from-literal=client-id=argo
```

After hitting the argo server url,manually I need to click on login option but after that keycloak page appears and then again a popup will come "Failed to login:Unauthorized"
Server logs:

```
kubectl logs argo-server-5c7f8c5cbb-9fcqk
time="2021-01-20T12:06:26.876Z" level=info authModes="[sso]" baseHRef=/ managedNamespace= namespace=default secure=false
time="2021-01-20T12:06:26.877Z" level=warning msg="You are running in insecure mode. Learn how to enable transport layer security: https://argoproj.github.io/argo/tls/"
time="2021-01-20T12:06:26.877Z" level=info msg="config map" name=argo-workflow-controller-configmap
time="2021-01-20T12:06:28.318Z" level=info msg="SSO configuration" clientId="{{argo} client-id }" issuer="http://10.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/auth/realms/demo" redirectUrl="http://xx/argo/oauth2/callback"
time="2021-01-20T12:06:28.318Z" level=info msg="SSO enabled"
time="2021-01-20T12:06:28.322Z" level=info msg="Starting Argo Server" instanceID= version=v2.12.2
time="2021-01-20T12:06:28.322Z" level=info msg="Creating event controller" operationQueueSize=16 workerCount=4
time="2021-01-20T12:06:28.323Z" level=info msg="Argo Server started successfully on http://localhost:2746"
time="2021-01-20T12:07:21.990Z" level=info msg="finished unary call with code Unauthenticated" error="rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = token not valid for running mode" grpc.code=Unauthenticated grpc.method=GetVersion grpc.service=info.InfoService grpc.start_time="2021-01-20T12:07:21Z" grpc.time_ms=0.379 span.kind=server system=grpc
time="2021-01-20T12:07:22.009Z" level=info msg="finished unary call with code Unauthenticated" error="rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = token not valid for running mode" grpc.code=Unauthenticated grpc.method=ListWorkflowTemplates grpc.service=workflowtemplate.WorkflowTemplateService grpc.start_time="2021-01-20T12:07:22Z" grpc.time_ms=0.075 span.kind=server system=grpc
```

Comment: Does anyone know what "running mode" is being referred to here?

Comment: Yes @lindhe ! read this line , and you will get it : https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/blob/1aea2c41798972ff0077108f926bb9095f3f9deb/charts/argo/values.yaml#L257

Answer (score 0):

I integrated ArgoCD with Keycloak successfully.

You have 1 clear/visible issue: **Yaml indentation is wrong**

make sure you keep the right indentation as per default values in helm chart :
https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/blob/1aea2c41798972ff0077108f926bb9095f3f9deb/charts/argo/values.yaml#L255-L283

Accordingly, your values should be:
( assuming your argo is serving with hostname `workflows.company.com` )

```
server:
  extraArgs:
  -  --auth-mode=sso
  sso:
    issuer: http://<keycloak_ip>/auth/realms/demo
    clientId:
      name: argo
      key: client-id
    clientSecret:
      name: "argo-server-sso"
      key: client-secret
    redirectUrl: https://workflows.company.com/argo/oauth2/callback
```

From keycloak side now, & under your client,  make sure you fill-in the Valid Redirect URL as per your ingress hostname :

[image]